# Convert ushort[] into byte[] and back

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, ushort

I have a ushort array that needs converting into a byte array to be transferred over a network.

Once it gets to its destination, I need then reconvert it back into the same ushort array it was to being with.

**Ushort Array**

Is an array that is of Length 217,088 (1D array of broken down image 512 by 424). It's stored as 16-bit unsigned integers. Each element is 2 bytes.

**Byte Array**

It needs to be converted into a byte array for network purposes. As each ushort element is worth 2 bytes, I assume the byte array Length needs to be 217,088 * 2?

In terms of converting, and then 'unconverting' correctly, I am unsure on how to do that.

This is for a Unity3D project that is in C#. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for `BlockCopy`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy(v=vs.110).aspx

and yes, `short` as well as `ushort` is 2 bytes long; and that's why corresponding `byte` array should be two times longer than initial `short` one.

Direct (`byte` to `short`):

```
  byte[] source = new byte[] { 5, 6 };
  short[] target = new short[source.Length / 2 + source.Length % 2];

  Buffer.BlockCopy(source, 0, target, 0, source.Length);
```

Reverse:

```
  short[] source = new short[] {7, 8};
  byte[] target = new byte[source.Length * 2]; 
  Buffer.BlockCopy(source, 0, target, 0, source.Length * 2);
```

using `offset`s (the *second* and the *fourth* parameters of `Buffer.BlockCopy`) you can have 1D array being *broken down* (as you've put it):

```
  // it's unclear for me what is the "broken down 1d array", so 
  // let it be an array of array (say 512 lines, each of 424 items)
  ushort[][] image = ...;

  // data - sum up all the lengths (512 * 424) and * 2 (bytes)
  byte[] data = new byte[image.Sum(line => line.Length) * 2];

  int offset = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < image.Length; ++i) {
    int count = image[i].Length * 2;

    Buffer.BlockCopy(image[i], offset, data, offset, count);

    offset += count;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. May you explain what the '{ 5, 6 }' and '{7, 8}' are doing exactly? Thanks.

Comment: @Oliver Jone: `{ 5, 6 }` are just *sample values*: `new byte[] { 5, 6 };` - creates a new array of byte with two items - `5` and `6`.

Comment: Thanks for this, just wanted to point out that you may need to use `Buffer.BlockCopy(image[i], 0, data, offset, count);` when doing a multidimensional array copy (0 being the starting position of each array as the for loop repeats)